# Adding objects to array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following is my `data` object.

```
data = {
    user: loggedInUser,
    shape: 4,
    width: currentThickness,
    color: currentColor,
    start_x: canvasX,
    start_y: canvasY,
    end_x: -1,
    end_y: -1,
    path_data: []
};
```

I would like to add some data to `path_data`.

```
data.path_data.push({
     x: canvasX,
     y: canvasY
});
```

But this doesn't seem to add anything to `path_data`.

What can I do to add objects to `path_data`?

**Edit: the complete code is given here**

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var canvasWidth = 490;
var canvasHeight = 220;

var currentThickness;
var currentColor;
var data;
var message;
var webSocket;
var loggedInUser = "user";

var mouseDown = false;

window.onload = function() {
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        mouseDown = true;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        mouseDown = false;
    });

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    currentColor = $('#selectColor option:selected').val();
    currentThickness = parseInt($('#selectThickness option:selected').val());
    var canvasX;
    var canvasY;
    if (canvas) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.lineWidth = currentThickness;

        $(canvas)
            .mousedown(function(e) {
                prepareStartPointPath(e);
            })
            .mousemove(function(e) {
                if (mouseDown != false) {
                    canvasX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                    canvasY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
                    ctx.lineTo(canvasX, canvasY);
                    ctx.lineWidth = currentThickness;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = currentColor;
                    ctx.stroke();
                    data.path_data.push({
                        x: canvasX,
                        y: canvasY
                    });
                }
            })
            .mouseup(function(e) {
                prepareEndPointPath(e);
            })
            .mouseleave(function(e) {
                if (mouseDown) {
                    prepareEndPointPath(e);
                }
            })
            .mouseenter(function(e) {
                if (mouseDown) {
                    prepareStartPointPath();
                }
            });
    }

    $('#selectColor').change(function() {
        currentColor = $('#selectColor option:selected').val();
    });

    $('#selectThickness').change(function() {
        currentThickness = parseInt($('#selectThickness option:selected').val());
    });

};

function prepareWebSocket() {
    console.log("preparing web socket");
    webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.99.70:2012");
    webSocket.onopen = function(evt) {
        onOpen(evt)
    };
    webSocket.onclose = function(evt) {
        onClose(evt)
    };
    webSocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
        onMessage(evt)
    };
    webSocket.onerror = function(evt) {
        onError(evt)
    };
}

function onOpen(evt) {
    console.log("Open");
}

function onClose(evt) {
    console.log("Close");
}

function onMessage(evt) {
    console.log("received: " + evt.data);
    re(JSON.parse(evt.data));
}

function onError(evt) {
    console.log(evt.data);
}

function prepareStartPointPath(e) {
    var canvasX;
    var canvasY;
    ctx.beginPath();
    canvasX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    canvasY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;0
    data = {
        user: loggedInUser,
        shape: 4,
        width: currentThickness,
        color: currentColor,
        start_x: canvasX,
        start_y: canvasY,
        end_x: -1,
        end_y: -1,
        path_data: []
    };
    ctx.moveTo(canvasX, canvasY);
    ctx.lineWidth = currentThickness;
    ctx.strokeStyle = currentColor;
}

function prepareEndPointPath(e) {
    var canvasX;
    var canvasY;
    ctx.closePath();
    canvasX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    canvasY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    data.end_x = canvasX;
    data.end_y = canvasY;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: the code you posted should be fine, actually..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code, look for error somewhere else, do you by any change reference "data" from outside of it's scope?

Comment: canvasX/Y should be not variable. But in ES6 you can use variables too (like [variable])

Comment: @loadaverage: It's absolutely fine if canvasX/Y are variables. It's x and y that would need to use the computed form, if they're variables containing property names rather than actually being the property names. I don't see anything to suggest that's the case, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder omg I mean if they are property accessors. I need some rest :)

Comment: also, your code works fine (check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mnbLujsL/)

Comment: You are right. The code works fine. It's just that the function that contains that code somehow doesn't get called.

Comment: could you update post and provide that function?

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this:
data.path_data={x:"canvasX",y:"canvasY"};

Comment: This won't add anything to path_data, it will set path_data to be an object with x and y properties.

Comment: doing this makes `data.path_data` being an `object` instead of an `array`